# How to solve recurrence $T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) +n$ using Master Theorem

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence using Master Theorem, but I'm not used to seeing recurrences with to terms ( i.e. T(n)) for the cost of operations. I'm pretty sure that a should be 1 and that f(n) is n, but I can't figure out what b is since there are two terms.

How should the recurrence be solved?

$$T(n) = T\left(\frac n3\right) + T\left(\frac{2n}{3}\right) +n$$

#### EDIT

**Original Problem**

A recursive algorithm has the following structure: it cuts the input of size n into three equal
pieces (of size $n/3$), does some work that takes a linear amount of time, and then makes two
recursive calls. The first recursive call is on a subproblem made up of one of the three pieces
and the second is on a subproblem made out of two of these pieces put together.

I think my recurrence is right based on the problem but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Would you feel comfortable using [a generalization of the Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method)? (Akra–Bazzi method, for -- if I didn't mess up -- parameters $k=2$, $a_1=a_2=1$, $b_1=1/3$, $b_2=2/3$, $g(x) = x$, $h_1(x)=h_2(x)=0$.)

Comment: Try T(n)=A*n*log n

Comment: Differentiate the relation to get $\Delta T(n)=\frac 1 3 \Delta T(n/3)+\frac 2 3 \Delta T(2n/3)+1$. Now you can use substitution to get $\Delta T(n)=\Theta(\log n)$ which yields $T(n)=\Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: @ClementC. I've never used that method before. I'm going to update the post with the original problem from which I derived the recurrence.

Comment: @A.S. is there away to do the problem without differentiation? Also, I just updated the post with the original problem.

Comment: Your recurrence seems to fit the problem - but for completeness you should write $\Theta(n)$ instead of $n$ if it is indeed linear and not $n$. Differentiation in this case is just discrete forward (or backward) difference and significantly simplifies analysis. If you "guess" $n\log n$, you can write down recurrence for $G(n)=T(n)/n\log n$ and show that $G(n)=\Theta(1)$. The purpose of all of these manipulations is to make structure more visible. Or you can learn Akra-Bazzi method which is the general purpose workhorse.

Comment: Use $G(n)=T_n/n$ instead.

Comment: @Michael That does not really help -- this is the right solution, but how is that going to help the OP to learn how to solve similar questions in the future?

Comment: @A.S. So then your original comment is the correct alternative to using master theorem?

Comment: Correct is not the adjective I'd use. Alternative is more like it - but as you can see Master's theorem has very limited applicability. What I did is a general method to attempt to solve recurrences. Note that both $\Delta T$ and $\frac {T_n}n$ satisfy the same recurrence, so you can choose either one. Do learn/understand Akra-Bazzi result.

Comment: @A.S. Are there any good resources on Akra-Bazzi theorem besides wikipedia? Also, for the differentiation method, did you use chain rule or something to get $13ΔT(n/3)$? And I can't really tell how the substitution was applied.

Comment: Check out the links at the bottom of the wikipedia article. Yes, loosely speaking, applying difference operator is like differentiating (that's how I think about it), so a chain rule applies in a wide sense (for not too rapidly changing functions). For substitution you re-express the RHS of the recurrence in terms of the same recurrence. Because coefficients add up to 1, you only need to count the depth recursive calls (each of them adds 1) and such a depth is $\Theta(\log n)$ when you go down by a constant factor on each step.

Comment: couldn't you solve this with the help of the [Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) ($\approx$ the Fourier series)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use Akra-Bazzi method.

But recurrence graph can help equally well.

If you have $T(n)$ as top node, then in the previous step you have had these nodes (sum of which gives $T(n)$)

$$T(\frac{n}{3})|T(\frac{2n}{3})|n$$

The next level has had these nodes ($n$ is added from the previous level):

$$T(\frac{n}{9}),T(\frac{2n}{9}),\frac{n}{3}|T(\frac{2n}{9}),T(\frac{4n}{9}),\frac{2n}{3},n$$

So you have at this level

$$T(\frac{n}{9}),(2)T(\frac{2n}{9}),T(\frac{4n}{9}),2n$$

Notice that because $\frac{n}{3}+\frac{2n}{3}=n$ each level will have a node with $n$ as a value. (2) above signifies the number of nodes.

Instead of trying to do this manually one level at a time, the structure of nodes after $N$ steps is the same as what in symbolic notation you would have after deriving

$$(x\frac{1}{3}+y\frac{2}{3})^N=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{N}{k}x^{N-k}\frac1{3^{N-k}}y^{k}\frac{2^k}{3^k}$$

Now you simply replace any $x^py^q$ with $T(n^*)$ and there you have the structure after $N$ steps, of course we will add $Nn$.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}  \binom{N}{k}T(\frac{2^k}{3^N}n)+Nn$$

The question of how many levels you have is easily answered by looking at $\frac{2^k}{3^N}n$ because this one will never go lower than 1. So N is obviously $\sim \log(n)$ because $\frac{2^k}{3^N}$ is exponential.

So in the end we can safely assume $T(n) \sim n\log(n)$. Since we do not know what $T(1)$ is and this will affect the evaluation since this value will be multiplied by the number of the leaf nodes, we take $T(n) \cong an\log(n)$ and try to calculate the asymptotic value of $a$. Even though it is not necessary, we just want to confirm the finding.

$$an\log(n)=\frac{1}{3}an\log(\frac{n}{3})+\frac{2}{3}an\log(\frac{2n}{3})+n$$
$$\frac{1}{3}a\log(\frac{1}{3})+\frac{2}{3}a\log(\frac{2n}{3})+1=0$$

or

$$a=\frac{3}{3\log(3)+2\log(2)}$$

and there you have it:

$$T(n) \cong  \frac{3}{3\log(3)+2\log(2)} n\log(n)$$